# Handler flag "application/x-httpd-php-source" returns an HTTP404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

My objective is the following:
When I type a URL without extension, I want to retrieve the php source code (as plain text).
When I type a URL with the .php extension, I want the server to process the php file and returns the result.

I have a .htaccess file containing the following code:

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sources/([^\.]+)$ sources/$1.php [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]`

When I access the `sources/defined-in_array-isset.php` URL, the php is processed by the server, and the result is returned properly.
When I access the `sources/defined-in_array-isset` URL, an HTTP 404 error appears.
Without the `H=application/x-httpd-php-source` flag, it processes the php file.
So I assume the `RewriteRule` is correct, but I'm doing it wrong with the Handler flag.

What should I use to retrieve the php source code as `text/plain` when I access the URL without the .php extension?

Comment: Works for me... By the way, I know it won't solve the problem, but you could as well use `RewriteRule ^(sources/[^\.]+)$ $1.php [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]` - it's bit shorter. =)

Comment: @Cthulhu Very odd... It doesn't work here...And I always used the shortest possible back references in my regex. But you're right, that's shorten in file bytes size.